# SCORE declaration in SQL is giving the following error

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to execute the below query with SCORE

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, SCORE 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID,SCORE(1) AS SCORE,NAME 
  FROM TESTTABLE 
  WHERE CONTAINS (NAME,'ABOUT(Test)', 1) > 34 ORDER BY UPPER(NAME) 
) 
where rownum <= 100 
order by score desc
```

But it is throwing **ORA-29908: missing primary invocation for ancillary operator**

Unable to figure out the cause. TIA for the help

Comment: How to reproduce the error without your table structure and sample data?

Comment: Lets say we are having a table with Name and ID and few more corresponding details Column.. Would require a output list with Name sorted in descending order according to the score..